# How to pre load imagename in Symfony while updating?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have title, image_name and blog_content and I'm saving these fields into MySql successfully. When I try to update title and blog_content are filled with contents but not the image.
I want to pre load an image name in image fields..

```
->add('title', TextType::class)
->add('image_name', FileType::class)
->add('content', TextareaType::class)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't, the display on this element must come from a user action

Comment: Your answer is correct but I suggest to extend it by pointing out that `FileType` shows only an upload button by default, so you need to print out the current filename yourself in the form layout.